# echo for one target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile which looks for .txt files in a directory and for each file makes echo of it name.

```
pchs := $(wildcard $(OUTPUT:%=%/*.txt))
txt:  $(pchs)
%.txt:
    echo $@
```

But when I start it the make utility returns me that nothing to be done for txt. Why?

**EDIT1:**

After some answers I understand what I should make with my makefile. Now it looks like this:

```
pchs := $(wildcard $(OUTPUT:%=%/*.txt))

.PHONY : $(pchs)

txt:  $(pchs)

%.txt:
    @echo pch is '$<'
```

But .PHONY does not help me the result of making is the same.

Comment: try to replace `%.txt :` implicit rule with explicit `$(pchs) :`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does make says, that there ist nothing to do? Because make calculates dependencies of targets, usually file targets. And the "txt" target produces no file.

.PHONY is for targets, that produce no file, like the clean target.

This here should work:

pchs := $(wildcard $(OUTPUT:%=%/*.txt))

.PHONY: txt

txt: $(pchs)
    echo $@

But, since you only echo the filename, I guess that you are post processing this output. Maybe you could formulate this post processing as a rule in the makefile?

Answer (score 0):

Because makefiles define what you want to have built.  And the .txt files already exist, so there is nothing to do.

To solve this there are a number of possibilities, but you should look into the .PHONY record if using gnu-make at least.

You can build fake-things out of the txt records and mark them as phony.  But...  it might just be easier to do this:

```
pchs := $(wildcard $(OUTPUT:%=%/*.txt))
txt:
    for i in $(pchs) ; do echo $$i ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because every `.txt` file you've listed in `$(pchs)` is up-to-date and Make decides to take no action.
Add them to `.PHONY` target to force rebuilding them every time you run Make:

```
.PHONY : $(pchs)
```

### UPD.

Also check that `$(pchs)` list is not empty, it could be done i.e. as follows:

```
txt : $(pchs)
    @echo pchs is '$^'
```

Comment: Hm, wouldn't it be more correct to state `.PHONY: txt`? This is `txt` dependency which should not be checked for physical existence and thus should be always triggered. So I think @JörgBeyer is right.

Comment: @dma_k, yes, actually, you're right, `.PHONY` for `txt` is anyway needed. But to force executing the recipe for each `$(pchs)` even if they are up to date, we need add them to `.PHONY` too.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Bash to determine the *.txt files, instead of Make:

```
txt:
        ls | grep -F '.txt'
```

You could also use this as a template to make a more general target, that echos any files that exist in the directory with a particular extension.

You may want the target to be PHONY, since it's not making a file.